# JQuery Drag & Drop Gridview inside an Update Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am sorry of this is similar to other questions however I cannot find what I am looking for exactly

I am creating a bootstrap modal where users can create a new thing (doesn't matter what), this is basically a form in .NET. The bottom half of the modal has a gridview where users can enter stuff in, lets say A B C and the rows can be dragged and dropped in any order. When the save button is pressed it saves the whole form data as well as the ordering in the gridview.

I have managed using google and JQuery (1.8.3) to make the gridview drag and droppable, however every time the button to add the data A B C to the grid is pressed the whole form postbacks and the modal refreshed, so you get the modal disappearing and reappearing. I would like to make this smoother so though add an update panel and while this works the whole drag & drop does not. After googling extensively I found that is because the update panel does a partial postback and as a result the JQuery function is lost. I was informed that the best way would be to rebind these. Now I do not really know JS let alone JQuery but I managed to get something working. Could someone please explain what is going on here and if there is a better way to accomplish my goals.

Gridview below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" CssClass="table table-hover" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Width="100%"></asp:Label>         
            <input type="hidden" name="sequence" value='<%# Eval("Sequence") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblA" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="B">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("C") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>

<div class="row">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtC" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnAddToGrid" runat="server" text="Add" />
</div>
```

Now in the code behind when the Add button is pressed, it builds up a datatable (actually does various other things due to complexity) including the values from textbox A, B & C and rebinds the gridview with the new datatable

I use to have the following to make the gridview rows drag & drop:

```
$x(function () {
            $x("[id*=gv]").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                axis: 'y',
                dropOnEmpty: false,
                start: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.item.addClass("selected");
                },
                stop: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("selected");
                },
                receive: function (e, ui) {
                    $x(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                }
            });
        });
```

This all works but when I press Add it refreshes the whole modal so the modal disappears and reappears which is undesirable. I then changed the JQuery to the following after google:

```
$x(init); function init() {
            BindEvents();
            Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
        }

        function BindEvents() {
                $x("[id*=gv]").sortable({
                    items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    axis: 'y',
                    dropOnEmpty: false,
                    start: function (e, ui) {
                        ui.item.addClass("selected");
                    },
                    stop: function (e, ui) {
                        ui.item.removeClass("selected");
                    },
                    receive: function (e, ui) {
                        $x(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                    }
                });
        }
```

And added an update panel around my gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" CssClass="table table-hover" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Width="100%"></asp:Label>         
                <input type="hidden" name="sequence" value='<%# Eval("Sequence") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblA" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="B">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("C") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>

    <div class="row">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtC" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Button ID="btnAddToGrid" runat="server" text="Add" />
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This does exactly what i want, you can press the button without the whole modal refreshing when inside an update panel. But what is this actually doing, i get it is rebinding the Jquery again but how?

Side note while this is working, i did notice yesterday that after adding this it took a very long time to add the rows to the gridview. Almost like 5-10 seconds from pressing add to grid button to it actually showing. Anyone have a clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery sortable plugin to drag and drop elements in the list

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi i get you can use the drag & drop sortable plugin, but my problem is more towards the modal refreshing when pressing a button to save it. So the modal (a bootstrap pop up sort of thing) closes itself down on postback. I have code to reopen it, but this behavior is not very smooth and undesirable. What i would like which is what the update panel does is a partial postback, but then the JQuery function is lost.